# How do I iterate over class members?

Tags: java, reflection

I am using the Java version of the Google App Engine.

I would like to create a function that can receive as parameters many types of objects. I would like to print out the member variables of the object. Each object(s) may be different and the function must work for all objects. Do I have to use reflection? If so, what kind of code do I need to write?

```
public class dataOrganization {
  private String name;
  private String contact;
  private PostalAddress address;

  public dataOrganization(){}
}

public int getObject(Object obj){
  // This function prints out the name of every 
  // member of the object, the type and the value
  // In this example, it would print out "name - String - null", 
  // "contact - String - null" and "address - PostalAddress - null"
}
```

How would I write the function getObject?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over a Class attributes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, you do need reflection. It would go something like this:

```
public static void getObject(Object obj) {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        //field.setAccessible(true); // if you want to modify private fields
        System.out.println(field.getName()
                 + " - " + field.getType()
                 + " - " + field.get(obj));
    }
}
```

(As pointed out by [ceving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402322/ceving), the method should now be declared as `void` since it does not return anything, and as `static` since it does not use any instance variables or methods.)

See the [reflection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) for more.

Comment: what if I have 200 fields in POJO/ data class of kotlin?