# How to loop over a Class attributes in Java?

Tags: java, attributes, loops

How can I loop over a class attributes in java dynamically.

For eg :

```
public class MyClass{
    private type1 att1;
    private type2 att2;
    ...

    public void function(){
        for(var in MyClass.Attributes){
            System.out.println(var.class);
        }
    }
}
```

is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

There is no linguistic support to do what you're asking for.

You can reflectively access the members of a type at run-time using reflection (e.g. with [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) to get an array of [`Field`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)), but depending on what you're trying to do, this may not be the best solution.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials: Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) / [Advanced Language Topics: Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

#### Related questions

- [What is reflection, and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)
- [Java Reflection: Why is it so bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392351/java-reflection-why-is-it-so-bad)
- [How could Reflection not lead to code smells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195914/how-could-reflection-not-lead-to-code-smells)
- [Dumping a java object’s properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603013/dumping-a-java-objects-properties)

---

#### Example

Here's a simple example to show only some of what reflection is capable of doing.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class DumpFields {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inspect(String.class);
    }
    static <T> void inspect(Class<T> klazz) {
        Field[] fields = klazz.getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.printf("%d fields:%n", fields.length);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n",
                Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()),
                field.getType().getSimpleName(),
                field.getName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet uses reflection to inspect all the declared fields of `class String`; it produces the following output:

```
7 fields:
private final char[] value
private final int offset
private final int count
private int hash
private static final long serialVersionUID
private static final ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields
public static final Comparator CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
```

---

#### Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 53: Prefer interfaces to reflection

These are excerpts from the book:

> Given a [`Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object, you can obtain [`Constructor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html), [`Method`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), and [`Field`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) instances representing the constructors, methods and fields of the class. [They] let you manipulate their underlying counterparts *reflectively*. This power, however, comes at a price:
>
> - You lose all the benefits of compile-time checking.
> - The code required to perform reflective access is clumsy and verbose.
> - Performance suffers.
>
> As a rule, objects should not be accessed reflectively in normal applications at runtime.
>
> There are a few sophisticated applications that require reflection. Examples include *[...omitted on purpose...]* If you have any doubts as to whether your application falls into one of these categories, it probably doesn't.

Comment: in fact, according to value of fields, I want to write or not write the value of each field?

Comment: @Zakaria: yes, you can accomplish this with reflection, but depending on what is it that you're trying to do, there are much better designs.

Comment: In fact, I have a report to generate from a class, and depending on the value of class fields I want to put or not those fields, what's the best design that can I implement.?

Comment: @Zakaria: Unless you want a general purpose highly customizable class report generator that works with _any_ class, you should just stay away from reflection and just write a specific taylor-made solution for this particular class in your application domain.

Comment: What I want to do is to test on field value, if isn't null I want to include it in report and vice versa. 
I have a lot of attributes and I don't want to test them all manually so I thought that using reflection will resolve the problem.
I will use it in one class.
I just want to add that the result of this function is an array of String. (String[])

Comment: @Zakaria: go ahead and try reflection out then. There's `Field.get` that you can use to read the values of a field reflectively. If it's `private`, you may be able to get around that with `setAccessible`. Yes, reflection is very powerful and it lets you do things like inspecting `private` fields, overwriting `final` fields, invoking `private` constructors, etc. If you need further assistance with the design aspect, you should probably write a new question with a lot more information. Perhaps you don't need these many attributes in the first place (e.g. use `enum` or `List`, etc).

Comment: generics has no use here. just do `static void inspect(Class<?> klazz)`

Comment: @polygenelubricants, thanks for such a detailed and nice answer.

Comment: i like how the arguments name is "klazz" - thats very klazzy :)

Comment: omitted on purpose?

Answer (score 49):

Accessing the fields directly is not really good style in java. I would suggest creating getter and setter methods for the fields of your bean and then using then Introspector and BeanInfo classes from the java.beans package.

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyBean.class);
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDesc : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    String propertyName = propertyDesc.getName();
    Object value = propertyDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(bean);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to only get properties of the bean, not the class? i.e. avoid MyBean.class returned by getPropertyDescriptors

Comment: @hbprotoss if I understand you correctly, you can check for `propertyDesc.getReadMethod().getDeclaringClass() != Object.class`, or you can specify a class to stop analysis as the second parameter like `getBeanInfo(MyBean.class, Object.class)`.

Comment: My problem with this solution is that getters (propertyDesc) are sorted alphabetically and I need original order of fields/getters.

Answer (score 30):

While I agree with [Jörn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java/3334217#3334217) if your class conforms to the JavaBeans spec, here is a good alternative if it doesn't and you use Spring.

Spring has a class named [ReflectionUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html) that offers some very powerful functionality, including [doWithFields(class, callback)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html#doWithFields%28java.lang.Class,%20org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback%29), a visitor-style method that lets you iterate over a classes fields using a callback object like this:

```
public void analyze(Object obj){
    ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(obj.getClass(), field -> {

        System.out.println("Field name: " + field.getName());
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Field value: "+ field.get(obj));

    });
}
```

But here's a warning: the class is labeled as "for internal use only", which is a pity if you ask me

Answer (score 19):

Simple way to iterate over class fields and obtain values from object:

```
 Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
 Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
 Map<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

 for( Field field : fields ){
      try {
           temp.put(field.getName().toString(), field.get(obj));
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
      }
 }
```

Comment: A class perhaps or any object.

Comment: @Rickey Is there anyway to set a new value to the attributes by looping each fields?

Comment: @hyperfkcb You may get an modification exception when attempting to change values of properties/fields you're iterating over.

Answer (score 6):

Java has Reflection (java.reflection.*), but I would suggest looking into a library like Apache Beanutils, it will make the process much less hairy than using reflection directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which sorts the properties alphabetically and prints them all together with their values:

```
public void logProperties() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
  Class<?> aClass = this.getClass();
  Field[] declaredFields = aClass.getDeclaredFields();
  Map<String, String> logEntries = new HashMap<>();

  for (Field field : declaredFields) {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Object[] arguments = new Object[]{
      field.getName(),
      field.getType().getSimpleName(),
      String.valueOf(field.get(this))
    };

    String template = "- Property: {0} (Type: {1}, Value: {2})";
    String logMessage = System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + MessageFormat.format(template, arguments);

    logEntries.put(field.getName(), logMessage);
  }

  SortedSet<String> sortedLog = new TreeSet<>(logEntries.keySet());

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Class properties:");

  Iterator<String> it = sortedLog.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    sb.append(logEntries.get(key));
  }

  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [`pojo-analyzers`](https://github.com/almogtavor/pojo-analyzer) which will also enable to access the getters and setters of the field (without reflection).

```java
@DetailedPojo
public class ClassWithStuff {
    public String someString;
    //many more fields
}
...
ClassWithStuff classWithStuff = new ClassWithStuff("myString");
// Pojo Analyzers will automatically create a class named DetailedClassWithStuff
DetailedClassWithStuff.list.stream()
    .forEach(fieldDetails -> 
            System.out.println(fieldDetails.getFieldValue(classWithStuff)); // "myString"
```

The library uses annotation processing so there is no reflection involved - the fastest solution possible.