# Spring Data Mongo update non-null fields of object?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

If I have a Java object with only updated fields set, for example (assume there is a third field `C` that is not set):

`obj.setA(1);
obj.setB(2);`

Is it possible to perform an `Update` operation that only updates `A` and `B`?  It appears my only options with Spring Data are to use `save()` (which would overwrite the value for `C` in the database to `null`), or use `update()`, which requires me to construct an `Update` object with a `set()` statement for each field in the object, as well as hardcode Mongo field names.  Essentially what I'm looking for is something that would do this update operation:

`$set:{'a':1,'b':2}`

I was messing around a bit with Reflection to try and do this (looking at the solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java)), which could potentially work, but it seems a bit hacky.  If Spring Data supports this somehow, I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is `o.s.d.m.core.query.Update` for exactly that purpose.
From the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.save-update-remove):

```java
// query: { "name" : "Joe" }
// update: { "$set" : { "age" : 35} }
mongoOps.updateFirst(query(where("name").is("Joe")), update("age", 35), Person.class);
```