# Java: Using reflection to fill all the setters from a class

Tags: java, reflection, no-framework

I have a class X with maybe 100 String in it and I want to do a function that mock an object of this class for all the setters which begins by "setTop".

For the moment I did this :

```
public void setFtoMethods(Class aClass){
Methods[] methods = aClass.getMethods();
   for(Method method : methods){
      if(method.getName().startsWith("setTop")){
         method.invoke ....
      }
   }
}
```

And I don't know how to do now and I'm not pretty sure I can fill all these setters like that. In my environment I can't use frameworks and I'm in Java 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANNOT** fill the setters because they are methods (functionallities), not values itselfs. But...
You **CAN** fill the value of the attributes (fields) of the class that corresponds to the getter.

---

Imagine you have a class:

```
class Example {
    String name;

    int topOne;
    int topTwo;
    int popTwo;  // POP!!!
    int topThree;
}
```

**Taking:**

- [this answer as model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java)
- your needs (`getTopXXX` will correspond to field `topXXX`)

You can **get** only needed fields with reflection in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    inspect(Example.class);
}

public static <T> void inspect(Class<T> klazz) {
    Field[] fields = klazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getName().startsWith("top")) {
            // get ONLY fields starting with top
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n",
                    Modifier.toString(field.getModifiers()),
                    field.getType().getSimpleName(),
                    field.getName()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
int topOne
int topTwo
int topThree
```

Now, do whatever you need inside the `if (field.getName().startsWith("top")) {` instead of a `System.out`.