# How to check two different classes attribute values are same

Tags: java, java-11

How to check two different classes having the same attributes in different order have the same values

```
public class Person {
        String name;
        Long age;
        // getters and setters
        // equals and hashcode    
}
```

Second class attributes in different order

```
public class PersonTwo {            
            Long age;
            String name;

            // getters and setters
            // equals and hashcode    
    }
```

Checking two objects equal

```
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setAge(122L);
        person.setName("Paul");

        PersonTwo person2 = new PersonTwo();
        person2.setName("Paul");
        person2.setAge(122L);
        
        boolean result = Objects.equals(person2, person);
```

This will return false, cannot make changes in both classes as they are from another library.

Instead of comparing each attribute value, any easy ways to do this?

Comment: You could use reflection since the getters have the same name in both classes, but for 2 fields? Just compare the fields manually: `boolean result = Objects.equals(person2.getAge(), person.getAge()) && Objects.equals(person2.getName(), person.getName());`

Comment: @fish classes have more fields, just shown an example, can you show the example using reflection?

Comment: You can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333974/how-to-loop-over-a-class-attributes-in-java

Comment: Is it really due to the order of fields? - because I don't see a way to do this, if not deliberately. Or does `PersonTwo.equals` include a line like `if (obj instanceof PersonTwo`)?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the attributes has no bearing on the equality of these objects.  They are distinct classes so `Objects.equals(Object,Object)` will return false regardless of the fields of those classes because it uses the `equals` method of the first argument to determine equality after performing null comparisons. Since both classes are part of external libraries you cannot hack a change to the `equals` method of either (which is just as well because that is a bad idea).

You could create your own version of `Objects.equals(..)` to handle this specific case.  A better approach would be to convert one of the instances into the other type and then you can compare them.  However, this assumes that `equals` is properly implemented for either (something that is out of your control since they come from external libraries).  You could also convert both of them to your own class (MyPerson?), implement a proper equals, and then you know it will behave as intended.