# Loop the variables from another class

Tags: java, loops, oop

Somebody knows or has an idea on how to simplify the code in getting the multiple variables from another class.
Below are the structure of my program :

```
Data.java
//composed of 30 variables with almost the same variable name
String dat1 = "";
String dat2 ="";
.
.
.
String dat30="";

Get.java
//here, I need to get the variables from Data.java and put inside   the loop

for(int i=0; i<=30; i++) {
 String dat1 = getField(Data.dat1).getData();
}
```

Is there anyway to loop the dat1~dat30 variable from another class? 
Thank you in advance for those who will help ;)

Comment: Instead of creating 30 individual variables, create a `List` or array of `String`, the create a getter method that exposes it in the `Data` class.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466038/how-do-i-iterate-over-class-members

Comment: It is not a duplicate. What I am asking is there a way to simplify the code in getting the variables since the variable names are almost the same. I can't change the Data.java. I can only modify the Get.java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java reflection API to read the values from `Data` object as shown below:

```
Data data = new Data();
//load data object with values

for(int i=1;i<=30;i++) {//iterate
   Field f = data.getClass().getDeclaredField("data"+i);//get each field
   f.setAccessible(true);
   System.out.println((String)f.get(data));//read value
 }
```

---

But, I strongly suggest you need to **restructure the class** so that it contains `String[] data` or `List<String> data` which will make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to store the variables of `Data` class then instead of storing in 30 different variables like `dat1`, dat2, ... store those in an array like `dat[30]`. by doing this you can access the fields just by calling `dat[i]` in your loop.

But if it is not possible to store the fields other than different variable then you can use [Class.getField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField-java.lang.String-) method to get the field by name. In that case you can get the field by calling like `getField("dat"+i)`.

Comment: Good answer with a variety of choices. +1